# Pattern matching using re.findall() gives Inconsistent results

Tags: python, regex

I am receiving blobs of text from an IRC server, and the data is not always sent in a consistent format.

This is the format that I'm expecting.

`:hey!hey.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #stream :message here\r\n`

I've developed this regex pattern to match it:

`:[^()]+![^()]+.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #[^()]+ :[^()]+\\r\\n`

And I'm doing this to assign the matches into a list:

`newlist = re.findall(':[^()]+![^()]+.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #[^()]+ :[^()]+\\r\\n',str(string))`

But, for example, when the input is sent in duplicate (doesn't happen often, but does happen)

`:hey!hey.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #stream :message here\r\n:otherhey!otherhey!tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #otherstream :othermessage here\r\n`

It matches the whole string.

SO!
I'm trying to combine this regex:
`^[^PRIVMSG]*PRIVMSG[^PRIVMSG]*$`
With the other one, so that the findall will return me every instance in the string that the full pattern is matched.

But the result is that I don't get any matches.
What am I missing?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to split the input at `\r\n` and work on the individual lines.

Comment: `[^PRIVMSG]` means match one character which is not `G` or `I` or `M` or `P` or `R` or `S` or `V`. You probably want a negative lookahead `(?!PRIVMSG)` but your regex around it needs a bigger overhaul. Perhaps see also the discussion of negation in the beginner tips section in the [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page.](/ags/regex/info)

Comment: Sorry for the typo; the link should be [/tags/regex/info](/tags/regex/info)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is because the quantifiers in your regex is acting greedy. making it non-greedy will make it work.

```regex
:[^()]+?![^()]+?.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #[^()]+? :[^()]+?\\r\\n
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OclSA0/1)

**Python example**

```
import re
text=":hey!hey.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #stream :message here\r\n:otherhey!otherhey!tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #otherstream :othermessage here\r\n"
print(re.findall(r":[^()]+?![^()]+?.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #[^()]+? :[^()]+?\r\n",text))
```

**Output**

```
[':hey!hey.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #stream :message here\r\n',
 ':otherhey!otherhey!tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #otherstream :othermessage here\r\n']
```

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted, your answer worked for me.

Comment: Edit* it actually doesn't return any matches for the normal scenario, where there is only one ':hey!hey.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #stream :message here\r\n'

Comment: It does. Check [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/OclSA0/2)

Comment: You're right, I had copied it in wrong